# Verilog: Why all elements of unpacked array must be initialized?

Tags: verilog, fpga, hdl

I have Verilog-2001 code as follows:

```
reg [5:0] Xpos [0:31];
reg [5:0] Ypos [0:31];

initial begin
  Xpos[0] = 6'd20;
  Xpos[1] = 6'd19;
  Xpos[2] = 6'd18;
  Ypos[0] = 6'd15;
  Ypos[1] = 6'd15;
  Ypos[2] = 6'd15;
end
```

And when I'm trying to read elements 0 from Xpos or Ypos in always block, I'm getting 0. Solution is to add for loop in initial block, which will fill rest of "bytes" of array:

```
initial begin
  Xpos[0] = 6'd20;
  Xpos[1] = 6'd19;
  Xpos[2] = 6'd18;
  Ypos[0] = 6'd15;
  Ypos[1] = 6'd15;
  Ypos[2] = 6'd15;
  for (k=3; k<32; k=k+1'b1) begin
    Xpos[k] <= 6'd0;
    Ypos[k] <= 6'd0;
  end
end
```

First question is why all elements of unpacked array must be initialized, and second, is there a more elegant way to do this?

Best regards,
Kamil

Comment: Are you getting 0 in simulation? You should be getting x's. Can you show more code?

Comment: There seems to be some simulator issue, as you should not get `0` in always block

Comment: I'm not performing simulations, but using FPGA device.

Comment: I think you should use non-blocking assignement "<=" instead of "=" and I'm not sure to understand your question. If you don't do the final loop, Xpos[0] is still all 0? This loop should not be required but seems safer to me. Because even with an FPGA, the default values may depend on technology/targeted device.

Comment: Exactly, without final loop Xpos[0] is still all 0.